# Show the subcategories of the chosen category in Rails, category and subcategory in the same table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I want to display the subcategories of the chosen category, when I add a new product.

Now I can select the main category, but the sub category can't display right. And there is an error from the Chrome Console:

> GET http://localhost:3000/categories/1/get_subcategories 404 (Not Found)

**Thank you**

---

#### Model: *app/models/category.rb*

```
belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => :Category, :foreign_key => "parent_category_id"

has_many :children_categories, -> { where "is_main_category = false"}, :class_name => :Category, :foreign_key => "parent_category_id"
```

#### Controller: *app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb*

```
  def get_subcategories
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { @subcategories = Category.where(:parent_category_id => params[:id] ) }
    end
  end
```

#### Coffee: *app/assets/javascripts/admin/products.coffee*

```
jQuery ->
  $('#main_categories #product_category_id').change ->
  selected_id = $('#main_categories #product_category_id option:selected').val()

  $.get "/categories/#{selected_id}/get_subcategories"
```

#### js.erb: *app/views/admin/products/get_subcategories.js.erb*

```
$("#sub_categories #product_category_id").html('<%=j options_from_collection_for_select(@subcategories, "id", "name") %>');
```

#### Views : *app/views/admin/products/_form.html.erb*

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @product] do |f| %> 

  <div class="group" id="main_categories"><%= f.input :category_id,
                                :collection => @main_categories,
                                label: "Main Category",
                                prompt: "Select main Category" %></div>
  <div class="group" id="sub_categories"><%= f.input :category_id,
                                :collection => @subcategories,
                                label: "Sub Category",
                                prompt: "Select sub Category",
                                class: "sub_categories" %></div>
```

#### Routes: *config/routes.rb*

```
namespace admin do
  resources :categories do
    member do
      get :get_subcategories, defaults: { format: "js" }
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Updated**:

After the route went the right place, I got the error below

- From the Chrome

  > ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest in Admin::CategoriesController#get_subcategories

> Security warning: an embedded  tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.

- From the Rails Console:

> No template found for Admin::CategoriesController#get_subcategories, rendering head :no_content

Comment: Have you set up a route for that action?

Comment: @TarynEast Thank you for your comment. Yes, I set the route for the action. I edited the post.

Comment: @floox did your route be placed in admin namespace?

Comment: @ŌkamiXOukarin , Yes, you're right. I placed the route out of the admin namespace. But It's not works after I put the route in the right place.  I got an error: `ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest in Admin::CategoriesController#get_subcategories`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The *get_subcategories.js.erb* file in the wrong place.

js.erb: app/views/admin/products/get_subcategories.js.erb

It should be in the **app/views/admin/categories/get_subcategories.js.erb** .

> Here is the complete code:

---

#### Model: *app/models/category.rb*

```
belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => :Category, :foreign_key => "parent_category_id"

has_many :children_categories, -> { where "is_main_category = false"}, :class_name => :Category, :foreign_key => "parent_category_id"
```

#### Controller: *app/controllers/admin/categories_controller.rb*

```
  protect_from_forgery except: :get_subcategories

  def get_subcategories
    @subcategories = Category.where(:parent_category_id => params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

#### Coffee: *app/assets/javascripts/admin/products.coffee*

```
jQuery ->
  $('#main_categories #product_category_id').change ->
  selected_id = $('#main_categories #product_category_id option:selected').val()

  $.get "/admin/categories/#{selected_id}/get_subcategories"
```

#### js.erb: *app/views/admin/categories/get_subcategories.js.erb*

```
$("#sub_categories #product_category_id").html('<%=j options_from_collection_for_select(@subcategories, "id", "name") %>');
```

#### Views : *app/views/admin/products/_form.html.erb*

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @product] do |f| %> 

  <div class="group" id="main_categories"><%= f.input :category_id,
                                :collection => @main_categories,
                                label: "Main Category",
                                prompt: "Select main Category",
                                :remote => true %></div>
  <div class="group" id="sub_categories"><%= f.input :category_id,
                                :collection => @subcategories,
                                label: "Sub Category",
                                prompt: "Select sub Category",
                                class: "sub_categories" %></div>
```

#### Routes: *config/routes.rb*

```
namespace admin do
  resources :categories do
    member do
      get :get_subcategories, defaults: { format: "js" }
    end
  end
end
```